# Angular filter - filter JSON results against array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, filter

I have a JSON object as follows:

```
{"email":null,"fullList":true,"listOfSomething":[
{
"contactEmailAddress": "fred@test.com",
"somethingId": 11060767,
"other": "whatever"
},
{
"contactEmailAddress": "fred@test.com",
"somethingId": 8499447,
"other": "whatever"
}, {
"contactEmailAddress": "fred@test.com",
"somethingId": 3234664,
"other": "whatever"
},  {
"contactEmailAddress": "fred@test.com",
"somethingId": 3233245,
"other": "whatever"
}
]
,"numOfResults":22}
```

In angular, I want to filter this list by an array of selected ID's, to match the key "SomethingID", within the key "listOfSomething"

My array of ID's to match against is formatted as:

```
[16199615,16199619]
```

My current filter just returns the entire list, unfiltered:

```
.filter('somethingFilter', ['somethingListService', function(somethingListService) {
domainsSelected = somethingListService.getSomethingSelected();
return function(array) {
    return array.filter(function(item) {
       return somethingSelected.indexOf(item.somethingId) === -1;
    });
};
}]);
```

I've tried so many different methods, but can find no examples where an array of numbers is matched against a nested JSON object, that has no numeric indexing.

Comment: Davin - my mistake, was trying to obfuscate company sensitive code before posting question and forgot to change a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example, of what I think you want to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/martinczerwi/kdmqvw19/3/

I've noticed, your filter returns true if the ID is not found, that's why the whole array is dumped. Also the ID array's name was wrong. Should probably be:

```
return domainsSelected.indexOf(item.somethingId) !== -1;
```

In my example I've added an ID from the data to the filter IDs.

Comment: That's perfect - can't believe I didn't spot that obvious mistake, been working on the code for too long! - Thanks martinczerwi !